# Selecting a Single Record for Each Type

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just need a sql server query for following scenario:

[image]

Need a query to get a single record of each vehicle type.

I have a table of Vehicle.

Passenger Car, Pickup Truck, MPV are the vehicle type.

There are 4 record of Passenger Car, 2 records of Pickup Truck and a record of Multipurpose Vehicle (MPV).

so I want a query to get the single record of each type.

Thanks

My desire output:

```
ID Model               VehicleType           Owner
1  LTD Crown Victoria  Passanger             XXXXXXXXXX
2  Tacoma              Pickup                YYYYYY
3  Explorer            Multipurpose Vehicle
```

This kind of output that I want.

Comment: Your question is incomplete... and by the way you have to show us what you tried...

Comment: The question is too vague and lacks context and detail.

Comment: Question is: for "passenger car", why do you choose "LTD Crown Victoria" and not Accord or Sentra or Seville?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Vehicle Type] FROM your_table
```

I see your edits. This query gives you exactly what you ask:

```
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT
    ID, Model, [Vehicle Type], Owner,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Vehicle Type] order by ID) AS t2
  FROM your_table
)  
SELECT ID, Model, [Vehicle Type], Owner
FROM t1
WHERE t2 = 1
```

Check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c8aa/22)

Comment: Hi Marco, This is ok. but you know, there are no. of fields more. That time distinct doesn't work. I want a complete fields(columns).

Comment: @Kamlesh: edit your question showing us desired result please, because I can't really understand what you need, sorry.

Comment: @Kamlesh: try my edited answer

Comment: No this is not working. You know what I want a record. Group by doesn't return any records, it works on Aggregates, sum etc.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it, but I am getting error "Column 'ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11692/discussion-between-kamlesh-and-marco)

Comment: @Kamlesh: my edited answer works as expected.

Comment: I got my output. Thanks for your help.